# Rank proof in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $3x5$ matrix. Is it possible $rank(AA^T)=4$? So I know that rank is the amount of leading $1$'s in a matrix. So this matrix consists of $3$ rows and $5$ columns, but how do I prove that the rank of matrix $A$ multiplied by $A$ transverse is $4$?

Comment: @ Sloan, thankyou for spending a moment on the edit

Comment: If $A$ has size $3\times 5$ (which normally means three rows and five columns), then $A^T$ has size $5\times 3$ and $AA^T$ has size $3\times 3$. So, it is impossible that $AA^T$ has 4 columns with leading 1's since it only has three columns.

Comment: why would $AA^T$ have 4 columns?

Comment: What I am saying is that $AA^T$ has size $3\times 3$, so it does not even have 4 columns!

Comment: oh sorry i asked the wrong question. Why would $AA^T$ be $3x3$ how did you calculate its row and column dimensions

Comment: When you have two matrices $A$ of size $m\times n$ and $B$ of size $r\times s$, you can only multiply $A\times B$ if $n=r$ (the number of columns of the first matrix equals the number of rows of the second matrix), and the resulting matrix will have size $m\times s$ (the numbers in the extremes). So, if you multiply $A$ (of size $3\times 5$) by $B$ (of size $5\times 3$) then the resulting matrix $AA^T$ have size $3\times 3$. Notice that the other multiplication $A^TA$ will have size $5\times 5$.

Comment: okay that makes sense now, thank you very much for your detailed help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is impossible, $AA^T$ is the composition of two linear transformations, the first from $\mathbb R^5$ to $\mathbb R^3$ and the second from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^5$, hence the dimension of the image can be at most $3$.

Comment: What do you mean the first going from $A^5$ to $A^3$? what is $A$ for you?

Comment: Sorry, my brain malfunctioned a bit for a while

Comment: no problem${}{}{}{}$